# How to make a static drop-down with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have multiple drop-downs that use the same array that have the numbers 1 - 5. Every time I select an option from the drop-down and select 1 for example, when I go to the next drop down, only 2-5 will be there. So if I select another option from the second drop-down, it will take that option out for future use. Is there a way to use the same array and still be able to use the same options for all those drop-downs?

I have a model called days:

```
class Days < ActiveRecord::Base
{
  DAY_AMOUNT = ['+ 1 Day ', '+ 2 Days ', '+ 3 Days ', '+ 4 Days ', '+ 5 Days ']
}
```

I am using simple_form_for gem and this is what my drop-down code looks like:

```
= f.input :day_amount, collection: Days::DAY_AMOUNT, :include_blank => "Same Day", :label => false
```

Lets say that this code above is in a loop 6 times. So the above problem will happen.
Is there any way of fixing this so every drop-down will be able to select all the elements from the array?

Answer (score 0):

You could hard-code the array of options into the dropdowns like so:

Change this:

`= f.input :day_amount, collection: Days::DAY_AMOUNT, :include_blank => "Same Day", :label => false`

to this:

`= f.input :day_amount, ['+ 1 Day ', '+ 2 Days ', '+ 3 Days ', '+ 4 Days ', '+ 5 Days '], :include_blank => "Same Day", :label => false`

Then you'll have the same set of options in each dropdown.

Comment: That does not work, even when you try = f.input :day_amount, collection: ['+ 1 Day ', '+ 2 Days ', '+ 3 Days ', '+ 4 Days ', '+ 5 Days '], :include_blank => "Same Day", :label => false

Comment: Leave out `collection:` and it should, I believe.

Comment: i tried it both ways, if i leave collection: out, it gives me an error

Comment: Sorry, I'm not versed in simple_form_for, but looking at the docs  [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections), it looks like you'll want `as: :select` if you're not using the `collection` option.  If that doesn't work, hopefully someone with a better understanding of simple_form can help. :/